# Solving y = 1/4 log(2) (8x – 56)^16 – 12

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

Hello I would like to know if whether I simplified y = 1/4 log2 (8x – 56)^16 – 12 correctly or not. Here are my steps:

1. 12 = log2 (8x – 56)^4 => I moved the 1/4 to the power using the log laws. 1/4 x 16 equals 4. I also moved the -12 to the other side which equals +12.
2. Log2(8x)^4 – log2(56)^4 = 12 => Since (8x-56) has the same log base I rewrote it as two terms.
3. Log2(8x/56)^4 = 12 => Using the log laws I divided the 8x with 56.
4. Log2(x/7)^4 = 12 => I simplified the fraction.
5. Log2(x^4/7^4 ) = 12 => I applied the power of 4 to the fraction.
6. 2^12 = (x^4/7^4 ) => I converted the logarithm to an exponential equation
7. 4096/2401 = x^4 => I carried the 2401 (7^4) to the other side. Dividing the 2^12 with 7^4.
8. ∜(4096/2401) = x => I fourth rooted both sides.
9. x = 8/7 = I arrived with this fraction.

My question is, did I solve the equation correctly? Thank you!

Comment: To be clear: Are you solving the equation $$y = \frac14 \log_2 (8x-56)^{16}-12$$ for $x$ when $y=0$? (BTW: One way to check your answer is to substitute it back into the original equation and see if you get what you expect.)

Comment: This would be easier to read if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hello Blue, the question just asks to simplify the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a good start. $12 = \log_2 (8x – 56)^4$ can be rewritten as $12 = 4 \log_2 |8x – 56|$ or $\log_2 |8x – 56|=3$ which leads to $|8x-56|=8$. Can you finish?

$y+12 = \log_2 (8x – 56)^4$ can be simplified to $2^{y/4}=|x-7|$.

Comment: I can finish. Thank you! One question, instead of |8x−56| = 8, is it supposed to be  |8x−56| = y + 8 since we don't know the value of y. Y is not stated to be as 0.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that it says to simplify. would that make any changes?

Answer (score 0):

The separation you did in step 2 is not valid. Log does not distribute over subtraction. Also (though your answer is way off by then), in step 7 you divided when you meant to multiply.

You can always check your work by plugging your answer back into the original equation you were trying to solve.

Comment: For step one, (8x-56)^16, so I brought the 1/4 to the 16 which equals 4. Since 16/4 equals 4. In this case, the equation only equals to y. So it isn't like 4=4 its the y = 1/4 log2 (8x – 56)^16 – 12. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't notice the 16. Scrap that bit, look at step 2.

Comment: No worries. So how do I solve the equation if I can't distribute the equation over subtraction? Do you know how? Thanks.

Comment: See Vasya's answer. At some point you need to apply the function $2^x$ to both sides.